# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{10}{2+3n(\ln n)^2}$ using limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find if this series is convergent using the limit comparison test

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{10}{2+3n(\ln n)^2}$$

I know that it's convergent, but what is the other series that I must compare with?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Compare it with $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln^2n}$.

Comment: why this series is convergent? by what i can approximate it?

Comment: It converges by the integral test. Use the fact that$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln^2x}=-\frac1{\ln x}.$$